# How can I fetch and display the fields in database for particular logged user

Tags: codeigniter

I have a 'employee' table name, then I create login page and I need to show user profile who log in. How to select particular user from id. I'm following this code, but show all user profile in database.

```
function empAll()
{
    $q = $this->db->get('employee');

    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach ($q->result() as $rows)
        {
            $data[]=$rows;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this your controller code? Your model code? Where is your database schema?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `get()` method alone, without any conditions. This returns all columns and all rows. If you want records for a given user, you would use `get_where()`:

```
$q = $this->db->get_where('employee', array('id' => $id));
```

You could also use `where()`, if you like:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$q = $this->db->get('employee');
```

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: @Atulsingh You need to provide that value. That will be the user account you want to pull.